# Trying to use WP shortcode in HTML

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to make a shortcode OUTSIDE POST/PAGE in WordPress.

The problem is, when I'm placing the `do_shortcode()` function, HTML automatically document the PHP code (e.g `<!--*php code* -->`).

What can cause the problem?

Comment: could you please share your code ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually place the do_shortcode() in your pages.  Somewhere in your functions.php or shortcodes.php file you set up the function and assign a shortcode to the function.

```
function myFunction($params = array()) {
    //function code here
}
add_shortcode('shortcodename', 'myFunction');
```

Then once that is done you can put [shortcodename] into your pages, inside square brackets just like that.  There are some plugins that will allow you to run php and enter it right on the page, but the default shortcode functionality requires you to add the shortcode first.